# MSTeams: Adaptive card header space text

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, adaptive-cards

We are sending adaptive card to user from MS teams Application using call graph APIs. While sending card we observed empty space on top of the card. See image below.

[image]

Below is what we are passing to API as payload. [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)

```
{
    attachments: [{
        id,
        contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive',
        contentUrl: null,
        content: JSON.stringify(card),
        name: null,
        thumbnailUrl: null
    }],
    body: { contentType: 'html', content }
}
```

We tried different way by giving subject to main object also name inside attachment but nothing is working out. I would like to know how we can give text on the header part or if it's not possible how we can completely rid off it.

Comment: Could you please let us know if you are posting the card in a chat or channel?

Comment: I am posting on both and this issue on both side.

Answer (score 0):

Engineering team has confirmed this is because the card is being sent by Graph API, there is no app associated with Graph API, and thus no app attribution is shown on the card.

Here is the document on how to specify TeamsAppId to fix this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-10-send-message-that-contains-cards-that-are-attributed-to-a-teams-app

Please note that this is still in beta version.

Comment: Can we override this information? Also, what is use of name and thumbnailUrl property in attachment?

Comment: Which information you want to override? Name and thumbnail are primarily used for File attachments and not cards.